# coldfusion cfform autosuggest - how to pass the locationid when the user is being suggested the locationname?

Tags: coldfusion, autosuggest, cfform

I've decided it's about time I started using cfform (3 mins in and I've already hit my first stumbling block!)

I want to have an autosuggest text input for users to choose a city. In my db I have locationnames and locationids.

e.g.

```
----------------------------
locationid   |   locationname
----------------------------
1      |      London
2      |      New York
3      |      Paris
etc.
-----------------------------
```

The user will start to type the locationame - I want autosuggest to show locationanames that match, but when they submit the form I actually want the locationid to be passed.

How on Earth do I do this with cfform?

Comment: You have a dilemma that has nothing to do programming code.  Location names are not unique.  In the samples you give, there is London, Ontario and London, England.  You need a plan for the user to give you specific information.  Once you know how you want to handle this, you can worry about coding it.

Comment: Too bad the person who downvoted this question is not brave enough to explain why.

Comment: The other thing to contend with is that the user might ignore the autosuggest and submit a value that is not in your db at all.

Comment: If you need it to match why not use a `<select>` That way the user can't miss spell something and you wouldn't have to worry about the user typing in the correct unique location. As little as kwispel's answer has to do with the question it would be a good solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks Dan and Will = really appreciate your help. As you say location names aren't unique (I was paraphrasing in the example in my question - I include the county for clarity).

Comment: Will - I have plumped for a select and then the jquery plugin Select2 for one of my instances which has worked very well. Thank you for your help :) Although for my other instance I still need a solution (I can't use a select here as it would contain 70,000 options) - I am looking for a jquery plug in that will do what I need (I'm hoping that http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ might ) and will report back my findings.. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't ever use cfform or any other UI-related Coldfusion crap in the first place.
Take a look at the excellent Typeahead JQuery plugin from Twitter instead: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: Minus 1.  While cfform bashing is popular on this forum, your answer has nothing to do with the question, which concerns the location id.

Comment: Thanks kwispel and Dan, indeed it would seem that the best practice is no longer to use CF for the front end stuff. I've gone with jquery plug in (details above) - thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just use the location name and look up the id upon submission, as long as your location names are unique. If they're not, as was the example about London, Ontario, then you need to include the state or county name in the lookup value, separated by commas so you can parse the location name back out again on form submission. A regular expression can take out the locationName in one group and the stateName in the next group. Then do a query where location = locationName and state = stateName.

Comment: Thanks dcoli - yes I agree (i was paraprasing in my question - I do do as you say and also include the county for clairty) - thank you for your help :)